# Does Ruby use $stdout for writing the output of puts and return?

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I want to know the output stream being used by Ruby to print these things at the command-line:

```
irb(main):001:0> a="test"
=> "test"
irb(main):002:0> puts a
test
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> a
=> "test"
```

Is `$stdout` used for `irb(main):002:0>` and `irb(main):003:0>`? And, is there any change in the value of `$stdout` between those two invocations?

Also, can some one point me to the Ruby source from where these things get printed/written?

Comment: Is `=> nil` confusing you? That `nil` is returned has nothing to do with STDOUT or STDERR. It's because `puts` returns nil, which is dutifully reported by IRB.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. And it's easy to test/prove to yourself. Try this at the command-line:

```
ruby -e 'puts "foo"' > test.out
cat test.out
```

The output will be:

```
foo
```

Ruby uses the STDOUT channel to output to the console. The OS then redirects that STDOUT to "test.out".

Try it with:

```
ruby -e 'STDOUT.puts "foo"' > test.out
```

and you'll get the same result.

If we do:

```
ruby -e 'STDERR.puts "foo"' > test.out
foo
cat test.out
```

You'll see nothing in the file, but "foo" will have been written to the console on the STDERR channel.

Ruby defines `$stdout` as a global you can change, and `STDOUT` as a constant, which you shouldn't change. Similarly, `$stderr` and `STDERR` are available.

Now, here's where it gets fun, and proves your question. Try this:

```
ruby -e '$stdout = STDERR; puts "foo"' > test.out
```

and you'll have the same results as when I output to `STDERR`, because, at `puts` was using the value for `$stdout` to select the output stream, and wrote to STDERR. Those stream values are picked up by Ruby from the OS when the interpreter starts, and are remembered during the run-time of the script. You can change them *if necessary* and Ruby will forget those settings when the interpreter exits, and reset itself to its normal state the next time.

You shouldn't rely on the implied/invisible behavior of changing `$stdout` though, because that leads to REALLY confusing code. Instead, I'd strongly recommend using an explicit `STDERR.puts` any time you're writing to STDERR and a bare `puts` for normal output to STDOUT. If you're intermingling output to both, then it'd probably be clearer to use `STDOUT.puts` and `STDERR.puts`, but that's your call.

Now, IRB is the same as a regular script running in the interpreter is, as far as using `$stdout` so writing output in IRB to `$stdout` works the same:

```
irb(main):001:0> $stdout
#<IO:<STDOUT>>
irb(main):002:0> $stderr
#<IO:<STDERR>>
```

And:

```
irb(main):003:0> $stdout.puts 'foo'
foo
nil
irb(main):004:0> $stderr.puts 'foo'
foo
nil
```

And finally:

```
irb(main):007:0> $stdout.isatty
true
irb(main):008:0> $stdout.isatty
true
```

We can't really tell any difference until we look a little lower; They're both TTY channels, with the standard STDOUT and STDERR channel numbers:

```
irb(main):009:0> $stdout.fileno
1
irb(main):010:0> $stderr.fileno
2
```

Hopefully that helps 'splain it.

---

I just realized that IRB's reporting of the return value of `puts` might be confusing you, causing you to think that the STDOUT is changing. That `nil` is returned has nothing to do with STDOUT or STDERR. It's because `puts` returns nil, which is dutifully reported by IRB.

Comment: Great answer!  I found it very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that happens is because IRB calls inspect on the object after each operation.

See Object#inspect for full details:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect

We can prove this by overriding inspect like so:

```
 ~ $ irb
>> class Foo
>> def inspect
>> 'hi'
>> end
>> end
=> nil
>> foo = Foo.new
=> hi
```

The only thing in your case that's hitting $stdout is the results of your puts command.

Hope this helps!