# Intercepting all puts and print statements from a Ruby program

Tags: ruby

I have legacy code, and rewriting this will take me a long while. Until then I need a solution that "works", even if it is ugly.

The main class of the code generates a long HTML string and stores this in an @instance variable.

Unfortunately, the larger framework also sometimes directly puts out something, through `puts` or `print`, and so can be used in a .cgi script.

I need to be able to capture all output from that framework, possibly filter or process it, before I send it to the user/visitor.

Is it possible to capture all `puts` and `print` statements from a Ruby script, and handle this gracefully?

In the final form, I will have to use `puts` and `print` anyway, but I need to sanitize some things there, possibly redirect, also optionally log output BEFORE I use puts/print.

Comment: If you found answer helpful, please consider selecting one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. By default `puts` and `print` output to the `$stdout` I/O channel. Reassign `$stdout` to a different file handle and output of those commands will go to the new channel.

Change where `$stdout` points.

```
File.open('spool.out', 'wb') do |fo|
  $stdout = fo

  puts 'hello world'

  $stdout = STDOUT
end
```

Save that to a file and run it. You should see a file appear called "spool.out" containing "hello world".

It's not necessary to wrap everything in a File.open block. All that's important is you reassign `$stdout` to a file handle, then reset it later, so it could also be done like this:

```
$stdout = File.open('spool.out', 'wb')

puts 'hello world'

$stdout.close
$stdout = STDOUT
```

At startup, a Ruby script has access to a number of different global variables and constants: `$stdout` will be the same as `STDOUT`, and `$stderr` will be the same as `STDERR`.

See "[Does Ruby use $stdout for writing the output of puts and return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343523/does-ruby-use-stdout-for-writing-the-output-of-puts-and-return/21344490#21344490)" and "[Putting the results of pp (or anything outputted to console) into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284694/putting-the-results-of-pp-or-anything-outputted-to-console-into-a-string/15285376#15285376)" for more information.

Comment: that works well - I upvoted both results as they seem good; I can make only one the selected answer though, so it was yours

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the print/puts function to add new functionality.
It could be done like so:

```
def print message
    #do something, like editing the message and logging it
    puts "Im here"
    super "#{message}:edited version"
end

print "hello world"
```

Result:

```
->Im here
->hello world:edited version
```