# How to programmatically run rspec test and capture output?

Tags: json, ruby, rspec

I am attempting to programmatically run a series of Rspec tests and capture the output of each.

What I have so far is this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.formatter = :json
end

out = StringIO.new
err = StringIO.new
RSpec::Core::Runner.run([file], err, out)
```

This does run the given file correctly, and in the terminal that I run this script from I see the JSON output that I expect... but since I'm giving the runner a `StringIO` stream, I would expect it to write the JSON output to that instead of stdout. In this case, the out stream is always empty.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can write everything that goes to `$stdout` to a file instead. If that helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894443/intercepting-all-puts-and-print-statements-from-a-ruby-program

Comment: I've tried doing something similar by doing `$stdout = StringIO.new`, but I still get the output on the screen and there's nothing in $stdout, it's a blank StringIO object.

Comment: I ended up working around this as I only needed to know if the spec failed or not, and the `run` function returns 0 on success and 1 on failure. Still no idea why the output stream doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm finding I have this problem in rspec 3.3, but it seems to be working fine in rspec 3.6 ...

Answer (score 1):

To run a series of Rspec tests I use Rake and to record their output I use a RSpec::Core::RakeTask in which I can specify rspec_opts with which you can pass a location and format for rspecs output.
Example:

Rakefile

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc "Run tests, recording their output"

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |task|
  task.pattern = 'spec/*_spec.rb' 
  task.rspec_opts = '--format documentation' +
  ' --format json --out logs/output.json' 
end
```

I made a basic github project demonstrating this at https://github.com/SamuelGarratt/rake_demo

The above Rakefile assumes your rspec tests are in a folder called 'spec' and end in '_spec'. Type 'rake spec' on the command line to run all the rspec tests and have their output recorded.